# How can I bind the Visibility property on a top level MenuItem to a ViewModel

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, menu

I’m using the following HierarchicalDataTemplate to bind a collection of MenuViewModels to a Menu control:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate
    DataType="{x:Type common:MenuViewModel}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=boolToCollapsedConverter}}" />
        </Style>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ContentPresenter
        Content="{Binding Name}"
        RecognizesAccessKey="True" />

</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

This is all working fine, however I have a requirement to remove certain menu items based on particular states (for example, I might only want to show an ‘Edit’ top level menu if the edit screen is active) To achieve this I have an IsVisible property on the MenuViewModel, which in turn is bound via a booleanToVisibility converter to the MenuItem’s Visibility property (Set in the HierarchialDataTameplate.ItemContainerStyle, which I think is where my problem lies)

This works fine on child menu items, but has no affect on top level menu items.

I’ve knocked up a quick example showing the problem [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2987370/src/MenuBindingExample.zip) (VS2010 .sln)

My question is: How can I bind the visibility property on a top level MenuItem to a ViewModel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    <Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=boolToCollapsedConverter}}" />
    </Style>


snip...

<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MainMenu}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MenuItemStyle}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the style at a higher level, e.g. `Menu.ItemContainerStyle`, this should only affect the top level though, so if you want to affect all items apply it implicitly via the `Style.TargetType` through the `Menu.Resources`.